# Searching for a sutta where Buddha talks about Nibbana

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras, nirvana, pali

I am searching for sutta where Buddha talks about Nibbana.

Also, there is one sutta where he says, "ah nothingness, great is this nothingness..." or something and his disciple replies, "What is so great where nothing happens".

Can anyone please help me find the sutta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AN 9.34](https://suttacentral.net/an9.34/en/sujato):

> Ven: Sariputta: “Reverends, extinguishment (Nibbana) is bliss!
>
> Ven. Udayi: “But Reverend Sāriputta, what’s blissful about it, since
> nothing is felt?”
>
> Ven. Sariputta: “The fact that nothing is felt is precisely what’s
> blissful about it.

*Sukha* or happiness for an unenlightened person is experienced when encountering pleasant feelings (from the six senses, including thoughts and the intellect) or when encountering the cessation of painful feelings (from the six senses).

But for a Buddha or arahat, *sukha* or bliss (in this context) is experienced when encountering neutral feelings, no feelings and Nibbana.

Please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/31463/471) for commentaries by Nyanaponika Thera. The supporting suttas are [MN 44](https://suttacentral.net/mn44/en/sujato), [SN 36.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn36.5/en/sujato) and [AN 9.34](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an09/an09.034.than.html).

From [Ud 8.1](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.8.01.than.html):

> Then, on realizing the significance of that, the Blessed One on that
> occasion exclaimed:
>
> There is that dimension, monks, where there is neither earth, nor
> water, nor fire, nor wind; neither dimension of the infinitude of
> space, nor dimension of the infinitude of consciousness, nor dimension
> of nothingness, nor dimension of neither perception nor
> non-perception; neither this world, nor the next world, nor sun, nor
> moon. And there, I say, there is neither coming, nor going, nor
> staying; neither passing away nor arising: unestablished, unevolving,
> without support [mental object]. This, just this, is the end of
> stress (suffering).

From [Ud 8.3](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.8.03.than.html):

> Then, on realizing the significance of that, the Blessed One on that
> occasion exclaimed:
>
> There is, monks, an unborn — unbecome — unmade — unfabricated. If
> there were not that unborn — unbecome — unmade — unfabricated, there
> would not be the case that escape from the born — become — made —
> fabricated would be discerned. But precisely because there is an
> unborn — unbecome — unmade — unfabricated, escape from the born —
> become — made — fabricated is discerned.

Comment: Exactly this! thank you.

Comment: @user17389 You could mark the answer as accepted to signal that your question has been solved (: